# Django - Can not upload file using my form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Here's the situation: I'm quite new to Django and I'm trying to upload some files using a form I created. When I click on the submit button, a new line is created in my database but the file I selected using the FileField is not uploaded.But I can upload files via the admin page without any trouble.

I've been trying to find a solution for a while now, but I still haven't found anything that could help me, so if one of you has any idea how to solve my problem I would be really thankful.

Here you can find some code related to my form:

**forms.py**

```py
class PhytoFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.PhytoFile
        fields = ['general_treatment', 'other']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PhytoFileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**models.py**

```py
class PhytoFile(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField("Date", default = datetime.datetime.now)
    general_treatment = models.FileField("Traitements généraux", upload_to='fichiers_phyto/', blank=True, null=True)
    other = models.FileField("Autres traitements", upload_to='fichiers_phyto/', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Liste - Fichier phyto"
        verbose_name_plural = "Liste - Fichiers phyto"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

**views.py**

```py
class AdminFichiersPhyto(View):
    template_name = 'phyto/phyto_admin_fichiers.html'
    form = forms.PhytoFileForm()

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = forms.PhytoFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.save()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.form})
```

**phyto_admin_fichiers.html**

```html
{% block forms %}

{% if user.is_staff%}

    {% if messages %}
      <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
           <div id='overlay-message' class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Fermer</span></button>
             {{ message }}
           </div>  
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
    <p>
     <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Synchronisation Fertiweb" name="synchronisation"/>
    </p>

    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
            <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 22%; text-align: center"><b>Traitements généraux</b>{{ form.general_treatment }}</div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center"><b>Autres traitements</b>{{ form.other }}</div>
        </fieldset>

      <p style="margin-top: 2%">
        <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Synchronisation Traitements généraux" name="trtm_gen"/>
        <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Synchronisation Autre" name="autre"/>
      </p>

    </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT 1** *after Sangram's answer*
**forms.py**

```py
class PhytoFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    general_treatment = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput)
    class Meta:
        model = models.PhytoFile
        fields = ['general_treatment', 'other']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PhytoFileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**EDIT 2**
I've been trying to validate the form for a while without any success .. Does anyone have any idea why ?

**forms.py**

```py
class PhytoFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    general_treatment = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput)
    class Meta:
        model = models.PhytoFile
        fields = ['general_treatment', 'other']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PhytoFileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def is_valid(self):
        valid = not bool(self.data.get('general_treatment', False)) and not bool(self.data.get('other', False))
        print("~~~~~~~~~> %s" % (format(not valid)))
        return not valid
```

I don't know why but my `not valid` is equal to `True` and I return it but I still get an error saying it hasn't been validated ... Maybe I'm doing it the wrong way and should not override the `is_valid` method

Comment: add Post in Caps `<form method="POST"`

Comment: Just tried it but didn't work :/

Comment: In forms .py add this `general_treatment = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput)` and also check file path  in Developer tool > Preview or response header

Comment: I've tried to add the line you told me to (I don't know if I put it where you wanted ^_^' you can see where I put it in the *EDIT* part I've made in my post)
And I didn'r find anything in the response header, but I've seen the files names in the `Form Data` in `Headers` tab

Answer (score 0):

***Try This***

**forms.py**

```
class PhytoFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PhytoFile
        fields = ['general_treatment', 'other']
```

**Views.py**

```
class MeasurementProfileCreateView(CreateView):
    model = PhytoFile
    form_class = PhytoFileForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('home')#Your success url 


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        fileform = self.PhytoFileForm(self.request.POST, request.FILES)
        if fileform.is_valid():
            fileform.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

see above code and change as per your code

Comment: Oh ! I've got something new now ! I've got a `ValueError` telling me that the PhytoFile couldn't be created as data wasn't validate ! Gonna try to fix that ;) Thanks for this start of solution ! :D

Comment: Thanks ! I'll let you know if everything worked out or not ^^'

Comment: I really can't find a way to validate this form ... I's starting to get on my nerves x) (I edited my post with the modifications I made)

Comment: check your database

Comment: put this in your template {{ form }} and check your get request response